# Laptop is not turning on with working charger

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

When I am connecting the charger to the laptop, the laptop is not charging (LED light is not on) and LED on the adapter/charger also turning off. I don't know what could be the problem?

Things I already tried and see the same behavior:
1. Tried with another charger.
2. Removed battery and try to turn on with AC power
3. Hold the power button for few seconds-minutes to get rid of static power

My warrenty got exprired few days back. (laptop is 1 year old)

Is this anything I can fix by myself?

Model: Dell Inspiron 15 intel I5 4210U

Comment: Still contact the laptop warranty people and, although it expired a few days back, argue that you would expect it to work for considerably longer than a year. I have a 7 year old laptop that works just as well as it did the day I bought it. Come up with other examples of technology you have that's older than a year and see if they'll still accept it for repair.

Comment: Can you [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1013499/edit) the question with the make and model of the laptop?

Comment: @Burgi: Please find the model

Comment: @BigChris: I called the customer service before posting it here. They were telling it is going to cost $179 to $279 + taxes and 90 days warrenty. I still can't decide spending almost $300 and getting only 90 days

Comment: OK, not a problem. When you say you tried another charger, did you try a completely different charge (mains cable AND charger/PSU unit)? From your question, the charger unit has an LED that is also not lighting up? Does this do the same with the other charger you tried? Are they both tested working with a voltmeter - your title says it works, but your question body isn't clear - does it initially turn on and then off? Finally, have you tried wiggling the charger connector in the laptop to see if the on-board connector isn't faulty?

Comment: Does your region use fused plugs? If so check to see if the plug fuse has blown.

Comment: @BigChris: Same problem with another charger also. I try explain again whats happening is: 

1. I insert the charger in the plug the green light on the charger is on-- indicates supply to charger is there.
2. Then I connect charger to the laptop -- the charging indicator light on laptop is not on and the charger LED which is on previously is turning off..

It happens the same with another charger(complete set).

The wall plug port is woking fine, as I tried to charge mobile it is working.

Comment: @Burgi: No.. Those are not fused plugs.. The plug is working fine as I tried to charge mobile, it was charging.

Comment: It sounds like an internal problem with the laptop charging circuitry (actually in the laptop). If the charger is on and then turns off when you plug it into the laptop. There might be a short or overload occurring and the charger circuits are cutting out as a precaution?

Answer (score -1):

My laptop (not the same model) doesn't automatically turn on when I connect the charger; there is a separate switch on the laptop for that.  However, it does start charging its battery if it isn't fully charged already.

You could search this web site to see if you can find more information on your laptop:

http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15-5558-laptop/pd?ST=+dell%20+Inspiron%20+15&dgc=ST&cid=282654&lid=5372774&acd=123098073120600&ven1=h3sq9DRU&ven2=p&ven3=630301386144830874

Are you sure that no one with that model of laptop wants to be able to charge the battery with nothing showing on the screen?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, you basically recommend to press the power button, the questioner already tried that.